# String replaceAll not working for $

Tags: java, regex

I am trying to strip out certain "<" and ">" from HTML code that is being generated by a 3rd party (of morons)

I am doing a replaceAll for some certain left over conditions that are not being picked up by our ETL people.

```
I have this string:  "<$200"  and I need it to be XML compliant like "&lt;$200"

string.replaceAll("<$200","&lt;$200");
```

does not work.  I assume it is some regEx funkyness. What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: `$` is a metacharacter in regex denoting end of string; escape it.

Comment: "$" has a special meaning in regex... It is not a normal character.. Use \\ backslashes to escape its special meaning and parse it normally..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`String#replaceAll`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replaceAll%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.String%29) accepts a *regex* as an argument, and not a String. `$` is a [special character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/characters.html) an won't be refereed as a String. Solutions:

- Use [`String#replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead - It accepts a String and not a regex:

  `string.replace("<$200","&lt;$200");`
- Use [`Pattern#quote`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#quote%28java.lang.String%29) - It returns a string representation:

  `string.replaceAll(Pattern.quote("<$200"),"&lt;$200");`
- [Escape special characters](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/names/syntax.html) by adding `\\` before the special characters.

Comment: @mmaceachran It is indeed can be used here, bu I recommend you to make sure you understand why other alternatives work as well.

Comment: Pattern.quote takes only 1 argument. And don't forget to quote the replacement also, it contains a $

Comment: @Ingo Thanks, I corrected that. Actually the replacement shouldn't be quoted, it's a String.

Comment: It should: Note that backslashes (\) and dollar signs ($) in the replacement string may cause the results to be different than if it were being treated as a literal replacement string; see Matcher.replaceAll. Use Matcher.quoteReplacement(java.lang.String) to suppress the special meaning of these characters, if desired.

Answer (score 1):

Use this

```
String demo ="<$200";
demo = demo.replaceAll("<","&lt;");
System.out.println(demo);
```